# Using long long data type in the correct way

Tags: c, loops, long-integer

What's wrong in my code? Why I am getting negative values when the first value is greater than the second one? This only happens when I use long long data type. I am just a newbie in here, so pardon me for this silly question. Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long long int a, b, res;

    while(scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)!=EOF)
    {
        if(a>b)
        {
            res=a-b;
            printf("%d\n", res);
        }
        else
        {
            res=b-a;
            printf("%d\n", res);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d %d",` is **not** correct for reading `long long int`

Comment: `printf("%d\n` is not correct for printing `long long int`

Comment: scanf is the problem. Not printf

Comment: @CannedMoose They are both a problem

Comment: @4386427 Yes you are right. My comment only considered the part of the question what the cause of the wrong comparison was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long long int a, b, res; /* firstly initialize all variable, enable warning flag */
```

As in the above statement `a`,`b` and `res` are declared as `long long` you should use `%lld` as a format specifier instead of `%d` otherwise it causes undefined behavior.

```
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b); ---> scanf("%lld %lld", &a, &b);
printf("%d\n", res);    ---> printf("%lld\n", res);
```

Sidenote, always compile your code with flag like `-Wall -Wpedantic -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror`.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d\n", res);
```

Its printing int, you want to print long long int, so you should use:

```
printf("%lld\n", res);
```

Same applies to `scanf()` too, use `%lld` as format specifier to take input of long long

Comment: Also `%lld` is needed in `scanf()`.

Comment: @Sergio..Right, I edited

Answer (score 1):

Every datatype has a specific **Format Specifier**. You have to use the valid one. The format specifier for **long long int** is **%lld** not **%d**.

Check the link for details about data types in C:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-types-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

not just are you printing int instead of long long, you are also reading just int instead of long long

change all your `%d` to `%lld`

if it doesn't work with your compiler, use `<inttypes.h>` and change `%d` to `%I64d`